# Команда в адресной строке debug=1

Tags: html

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делает данная команда? Заказчик скинул ссылку, где /название_сайта.ру/debug=1 и спросил "что это за мусор". Пробовал гуглить но не нашел ответа на вопрос(
Подскажите пожалуйста это он дурак или эту команду нужно как-то убрать?
Сайт на html (с bootstrap).

Comment: Быть может это артефакт от проверки работы цели в Яндекс.Метрике `http://example.com/?_ym_debug=1`

Comment: @Behmetev к сожалению нет, там просто ?debug=1
не понятно..,(

Comment: Тогда проверьте где в коде используется GET запрос `debug`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего вы хотели написать не

`название_сайта.ру/debug=1` а

`название_сайта.ру?debug=1`,

это обычные параметры запроса, на сервер передается переменная debug со значением 1. Могу припустить, что эта переменная включает дебаг на сайте, это никак не связано с `bootstrap`